# How to convert 24-hour numeric values to time using lubridate? (R)

Tags: r

```
library(lubridate)
df <- tibble(var1 = c(0, 30, 830, 1400, NA), var2 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A"))
```

I have a set of numeric values representing 24 hours, e.g., 0 = 0:00, 30 = 0;30, 830 = 8:30, 1400 = 14:00. I would like to convert these values to a time field in `lubridate`. However, I get the following message when I try using `hm(df)`

```
Warning message:
In .parse_hms(..., order = "HM", quiet = quiet) :
  Some strings failed to parse, or all strings are NAs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add a variable number of leading zeroes, then convert to posixct and at last extract just the hours and minutes.

```
strftime(strptime(sapply(paste0("0000", df), function(i) substring(i, nchar(i) - 3, nchar(i))), "%H%M"), format = "%H:%M")

   00000   000030  0000830 00001400   0000NA 
 "00:00"  "00:30"  "08:30"  "14:00"       NA
```

Comment: I've modified my original post so it's in a dataframe. If my dataframe has multiple columns, how would I modify your code to only specify the column with my numeric variables (`var1`)?

Comment: just replace `df` with `df$var1`